# mottie tablesorter: force sortText (NOT sortNatural)

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've made a custom parser like so:

```
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'custom-sort-value',
        is: function(s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            return $(cell).data('sort-value').toString();
        },
        type: 'text'
    });
```

However, I've noticed it ends up using the tablesorter function `sortNatural` (because of `type: 'text'`). However, I need it to just do a basic alphabetical sort, like tablesorter's `sortText` (I can't have it split the strings and compare each split). Is there a way I can force it to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't need a custom parser to grab text from an attribute. The fork of tablesorter attempts to get a custom sort string from `data-text` (which can be modified by the [`textAttribute` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute)), but only when the [`textExtraction` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction) is set to "basic" (default setting).

So, to use the basic `sortText` sort, use the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textsorter) to set your custom sort function by column:

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({
    textSorter : {
      // replace INDIVIDUAL COLUMN text sorter functions
      0 : function(a, b, direction, columnIndex, table){
        // same as $.tablesorter.sortText (basic alphabetical sort)
        // direction: true = ascending; false = descending
        // columnIndex: zero-based index of the current table column being sorted
        // table: table DOM element (access options by using table.config)
        return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
      },
      1 : $.tablesorter.sortText,    // same as the function in column 0 above (modified in v2.12)
      2 : $.tablesorter.sortNatural, // renamed v2.12 from $.tablesorter.sortText - performs natural sort
      3 : Array.AlphanumericSort     // alphanumeric sort from sugar (http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting)
    }
  });
});
```